# How can i use a hook in a conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, conditional-statements

how can i use a hook like below in an if statement? I am trying use a button click to indicate a change in category. once the change in category is set, pagination aligns the count in accordance to.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState('')

let count = ContentsCount

if (category) {
  count = filteredContentCount
}



/// ...

 <ul className="dropdown-menu">
  {categories.map(category => (
    <li
      style={{
        cursor: 'pointer',
        listStyleType: 'none'
      }}
      key={category}
      onClick={() => setCategory(category)}
    >
      <a className='dropdown-item'>{category}</a>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

...

```
{resPerPage <= count && (
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <Pagination
      activePage={currentPage}
      itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
      totalItemsCount={contentsCount}
      onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
      nextPageText={'Next'}
      prevPageText={'Prev'}
      firstPageText={'First'}
      lastPageText={'Last'}
      itemClass="page-item"
      linkClass="page-link"
    />
  </div>
)}
```

this is the request in the backend for content and its item counts. ideally the goal is to get total count per category.

```
exports.getContents = asyncErrors (async (req,res,next) =>{


    const contentsCount = await Content.countDocuments(); //162
    console.log(contentsCount)

    const resPerPage = 9;

    const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Content.find(),req.query).search().filter().pagination(resPerPage)

    let contents = await apiFeatures.query;
    console.log(contents)
    let filteredContentCount = contents.length;
    console.log(filteredContentCount)

    /*  check for category request
        assign total amount of objects within a  category to a variable/constant

        if(category.req){
            let contentCount = category.counter
        }

    */



     setTimeout(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            contents,
            contentsCount,
            resPerPage,
            filteredContentCount

        })
    }, 2000);

})
```

filtering and pagination:

```
class APIFeatures {
    constructor(query,queryStr){
        this.query = query;
        this.queryStr = queryStr;
    }
    search(){

        const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword ? {
            name:{
                $regex:this.queryStr.keyword,
                $options:'i'
            }
        }:{}

        console.log(keyword)
        this.query = this.query.find({...keyword})
        return this;
    }

    filter(){
        const queryCopy = {... this.queryStr}
        //removing fields from the query

        // console.log(queryCopy)
        const removeFields =['keyword','limit','page']
        removeFields.forEach(el => delete queryCopy[el]);

        // console.log(queryCopy)


        //advance filter for title,etc..
        let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryCopy)
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g,match=>`$${match}`)

        console.log(queryCopy)
        console.log(queryStr)

        this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
        return this;

    }
    pagination(resPerPage){
        const currentPage = Number(this.queryStr.page) || 1;
        const skip = resPerPage * (currentPage-1)

        this.query = this.query.limit(resPerPage).skip(skip)
        return this
    }
}

module.exports =  APIFeatures
```

main react code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import { MetaData } from './MetaData'
import { Textarea } from '@nextui-org/react';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination'
import ContCard from './Card/ContCard'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getContents } from '../actions/contentActions'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
// import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import { Dropdown } from 'rsuite';
import { MDBDropdown, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownItem } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

export default function Content() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert()
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
    const { loading, error, contents, contentsCount, resPerPage, filteredContentCount } = useSelector(state => state.contents);
    const categories = [
        ...
    ]
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
            return alert.error(error)
        }
        dispatch(getContents(currentPage, category));
    }, [dispatch, alert, error, currentPage, category])

    function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
        setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
    }

    // const setCategories = (category)=>{
    //     setCategory(category)
    // }
    var count = contentsCount;
    console.log('before:' + count)

    function setCategories(category) {
        // count = filteredContentCount
        // console.log(' filtered:' + count)
        setCategory(category)
    }
    console.log('after count:' + count)




    return (
        <Fragment>

            
            {loading ? <h1>Loading ...</h1> : (
                <Fragment>
                    <section id="contents" className="container mt-5">
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Categories
                            </button>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                {categories.map(category => (
                                    <li
                                        style={{
                                            cursor: 'pointer',
                                            listStyleType: 'none'
                                        }}
                                        key={category}
                                        // onClick={() => setCategory(category)}
                                        onClick={() => setCategories(category)}
                                    >

                                        <a className='dropdown-item'>{category}</a>
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row" id='cards'>
                            <Fragment>
                                <div className="col-6 col-md-9" >
                                    {category}
                                    <div className="row" >
                                        {contents && contents.map(content => (
                                            <ContCard key={content._id} content={content} col={4} />
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Fragment>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    {(resPerPage <= count)  && (
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                            <Pagination
                                activePage={currentPage}
                                itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
                                totalItemsCount={contentsCount}
                                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                                nextPageText={'Next'}
                                prevPageText={'Prev'}
                                firstPageText={'First'}
                                lastPageText={'Last'}
                                itemClass="page-item"
                                linkClass="page-link"
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

I am looking to fix pagination. It disappears once you have clicked to set the category button also pagination doesnt keep track of all the possible pages per category.

Comment: Can you try using different variable names, there are two variables as category with different purposes.

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne no, i need the category variable to be used so as to indicate a change in category.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly. [Hooks should be called unconditionally](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). Why do you need to conditionally update count? It should be derived from `categories` or `filteredContent`.

Comment: @Valentin the idea is when you click a button, count updates as a result of being assigned the value of filteredContentCount.

Comment: It seems to be imperative programming and it's not what React should be. Maybe you can post more code?

Comment: @Valentin sure thing. i've added the express code for the backend. Hopefully you can get an idea as to what i am doing. - thanks

Comment: More of the React code would be more on point.

Comment: @Valentin its been added!